# How to share screen (PDF) and webcam (of me) and tablet pen input (from surface)?

Tags: skype, zoom-meeting, pen, collaboration, whiteboard

I am looking to teach a language, and need to share three things at once:

1. Screen (usually PDF, but also video and/or audio streamed from web)

   - I can do this on skype or zoom
2. Webcam of me, concurrent with above, but full view of me (not a thumbnail). E.g. split screen.

   - I can do 1 & 2 concurrently with Skype for sure, poss also zoom
3. Tablet as a white board. I use a Windows laptop, and also have a surface go. I need to add my surface go as a kind of graphics tablet, so I can write on a white board and share this, in a big size (not a thumbnail)

   - I CANNOT switch fully to a surface, the existing presentation system (windows 10 laptop) is the required base system. The base presentation system is not, and will not be, touch or pen enabled.
   - I do not know what tool to use for this at all!

Answer (score -1):

I think using Zoom will be the go.

If you are in Zoom, you can share your screen, (when you click your ‘Share Screen’ button, Zoom should tell you how to share with all of the different options).

I don’t believe that you can share you screen as well as have you on the screen.

And lastly, to get a whiteboard, you need to press the share screen button, again, I don’t think you can have you in the screen, unless you are using another device calling someone else on Zoom, and you can use that to have on the screen.

Hope this helps,

LittleKitten